# has_many validation on nested attribute for Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, shoulda

I've got the following two models:

```
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :homes, inverse_of: :human, validate: true, autosave: true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :homes, allow_destroy: true
end


class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :human, inverse_of: :homes

 validates :human, presence: true
 validates :address, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :human_id }
 validates :post_code, length: { maximum: 25 }
end
```

And the following spec on `spec/models/human_spec.rb`

```
it { should have_many(:homes) }
```

Which fails with:

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:homes) }
   Expected Human to have a has_many association called homes (homes should have :validate => )
 # ./spec/models/human_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tracked this down to here:

```
  https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb  (Line 263)
```

Which seems to suggest that validate: true requires a specific validate: callback, with validates methods not being sufficient/acceptible. How do I tell a has_many association to run validates callbacks, but not require :validate =>  ?

Comment: Off topic, but shouldn't inverse be `:human` (singular)?

Comment: thanks! Edited as per @PinnyM 's comment

Comment: I don't think you can use that shoulda matcher to validate an association that has validate: true. You may have to test it 'by hand' in this case.